# Data set for Market Basket Analysis

Tags: dataset, market-basket-analysis

I am writing my Bachelor thesis about Market Basket Analysis and I need a data set to make an example of this analysis, can anyone recommend me something?

It would be very good if data would be big enough, for example around 1000 rows or more and with names of items purchased not just numbers...

Any help would be very helpful!

Comment: I tried search in google, but all data sets I could find was impersonal, like a lot of rows with item numbers, and it doesn't say what kind of items are there...

Comment: Google searching turned up this http://www.salemmarafi.com/code/market-basket-analysis-with-r/comment-page-1/ Groceries data set.  Please provide more detail to your question, e.g. what do you consider big enough and why.

Comment: yes, this one is very good, but I can't use it, because there is example with it, and I have to do it by myself...

Answer (score 1):

For others who are seeking for dataset related to market basket,I found dataset in kaggle interesting
https://www.kaggle.com/puneetbhaya/online-retail